Ubuntu 20.04 slow file transfer across disks
I am trying to move files from a SSD to a HDD on Ubuntu20.04 and the file transfers are ridiculously slow. The transfer has been going on for half an hour and i only got 1.3GB through. All of my researches have hit a dead wall as most hits talk about network or USB interfaces issues.
-SSD: 500GB, ext4, boot drive, 95% use
-HDD: 2TB, ext4, mounted on /media/disk
I attempted several solutions.

Dropping the ram cache (The system is using 28.5GiB of cache out of 31.1 avaliable), but the drop does not work and hangs forever. Using this solution
Using ionice through iotop to increase priority, which helps.
Using rsync instead of cp

No matter what i try, i only get at best 2.5MBps on average. Considering that 99% of the files are 3.5MB and above, i think that the transfer speed should be much faster. I have a Seagate ST2000DM008 7500rpm 2TB hdd.

How are the disks connected exactly? The SSD is likely SATA and not the bottleneck. What about the HDD? USB? If USB, USB 1.0, 2.0, 3.0? The mount point really isn't interesting at all... What does "nmon" (for example) show while you're transferring files?

You should also be exact with your units. Usually "B" denotes a byte, and "b" a bit, especially when talking about communication speeds. Is your 2.5 Mbps megaBYTES or megaBITS per second?

@Hans-MartinMosner The SSD is connected to a m.2 slot but i think it is a SATA interface, either way it shouldn't be the bottleneck. The HDD is internal and connected through SATA.
Regarding nmon output (thanks for the new tool i discovered) i see varying read and writes speed of around 600KB to 35MB with frequent stops. The Busy column often goes past the 100% limit on the HDD. Overall the maximum speed is within the range of what i expect but it seems like it very frequently stops, dropping the average transfer rate.

@Hans-MartinMosner I updated the units according to the exact letters used by the diagnostic tools i have.

taking a wild guess: the device you're copying to is formatted as NTFS? That's not an extremely well-supported file system on linux, and Ubuntu 20.04 is very very old, so that it only has an obsolete and very slow driver for it.

@MarcusMüller Both of the drives are formatted ext4.
